# PostgreSQL Error: The program can't start because libpq.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: c, visual-studio, postgresql

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to build a program in `C` that can operate on a PostgreSQL database.

Everything is fine in VS, no compile errors, everything looks good.

When I click to debug and run, the code compiles, but then I get a pop up that says:

`The program can't start because libpq.dll is missing from your computer`

I've installed PostgreSQL and added the folder containing all the necessary files to my `include` and `linker` paths, but to no avail.
I cannot figure out why I am still getting this message?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You must've linked libpq dynamically, which means you need the DLL to run. Start by putting it next to the .exe. Search for "DLL search path" for details.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean "put it next to the .exe"? The PostgreSQL exe?

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with PostGreSQL. Your program was compiled to use a dynamic library, and the OS is unable to find that library. You need the DLL somewhere in the search path.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer's surprisingly simple.

The issue you're seeing comes from the compiled application not being able to find the PostgreSQL libraries.  The libpq.lib is used to compile the application, and it links to the DLL at run-time.  You can either add it to your system wide path, or bundle the DLL with your application.  (I'd add it on the development machine, and bundle the redistributable for a installer package.)

To include it in your path try:

1. Right click on "My Computer" and select Properties
2. Then Click on "Advanced System Settings".
3. Click the "Environment Variables" button at the bottom of the dialog box.
4. It will pop up a dialog with a group box labeled "System Variables".  Find the one in the list box that has a Variable name of "Path".
5. Now, add the path of the PostgreSQL library folder to the path with a ";" separator.
6. Now logout or reboot.  It's *imperative* that you at least log out of Windows and log back in for the Visual Studio debugger to pickup the additional executable module paths (that Path variable).  Ideally, rebooting sends the new system path to all applications in the system at boot time.

If the Path variable has "C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem" in it, you would add ";C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\libraries" to make it look like "C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\libraries".

Be aware that your path will be *really* long in most cases.   Just add it to the end.

Good luck!

Comment: Ahh, the joys of editing PATH on Windows with a 3-pixels-wide single-line edit box...

Comment: Awesome! It worked! I am actually getting a new error now, but I don't think it's related. The error message is `The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)`

Comment: Excellent!  So I'm guessing at this, but since the error code 0xc000007b means INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT, I'm going to say the error is likely in the 32 or 64 "bittedness" of your application.  Essnetialy, if the PostgreSQL DLL file is a 64 bit DLL, and your application binary is a 32 bit binary, it can't load the DLL into the address space.  Check to be sure that the program you're building is 64 bit if the PostgreSQL install is a 64 bit install, or 32 bit if it's a 32 bit install.

Comment: @PhorkusMaximus How do I check the "bittedness" of the program I'm building (in Visual Studio)?

Answer (score 2):

I have Win10 64 bit and this worked for me.

Get portable version of HeidiSQL and copy libpg.dll from the archive to the HeidiSQL installation folder on your computer.

Works like a charm.

Comment: Effective answer!

Comment: In my case, my HeidiSQL has old version of `libpq.dll`. It gave me an error `authentication method 10 not supported`. After installing postgres 15 I replaced `libpq.dll` with newly installed one from postgres. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer is in the right direction, but didn't work for me.  I would have just commented on it, but I don't have the XP to do that.  For me, I had to add:

> C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\bin

and

> C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\include

to the PATH variable to get it to work (based on hours of going in circles and stumbling across this suggestion elsewhere).

TBH - I'm not totally sure which one got it to work, I didn't remove either to find out.  But the Libraries certainly didn't work for me and somewhere in my research I saw a note about each of these using the same logic as above.

Comment: I did this as well and it worked for me. I'm not experienced with Windows that much, so I don't want to tinker too much as well. 

First I added `*\include` in *User Variables* and *System Variables*, didn't work. Then I added `*\bin` on *User Variables*, and not yet in *System Variables*, then it did work.

If this might help any one's searches, I'm using `rocket v0.5.0` and `diesel 1.4.z`, and of course other libraries. But I think this is coming from `diesel`'s requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest PostgreSQL 16 client installation, you need to copy the following additional libraries to successfully load libpq.dll:

```
libssl-3-x64.dll
libcrypto-3-x64.dll
libintl-9.dll
libiconv-2.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
```

Note that the last two dependencies seem to be dynamically loaded and do not show in dumpbin.exe inspection. You can temporarily use psql.exe to receive feedback on the missing libraries though.