# Postgres with C leads to non zero exit code

Tags: c, postgresql

I am trying to do some work with postgres database using C language. I got it successfully imported using cmake, although when I run any libpq-fe related code, such as in example below, I get non zero exit code.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Before version\n");
    int lib_ver = PQlibVersion();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error:
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)

Also I want to note that it doesn't even print the first line.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
To clarify, here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(importer C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -I${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/pgsql/include -L/${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/pgsql/lib")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/pgsql/include")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -L${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/pgsql/lib")

# Next line is not required, without it given path will be checked too.
set(PostgreSQL_ROOT "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/pgsql")
find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)

include_directories (${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

set(SOURCES main.c)
add_executable(importer ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(importer PRIVATE ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(importer PRIVATE Threads::Threads)

set(SOURCE_FILES CMakeLists.txt main.c)
```

and here is the output from parsing cmake:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\lukas\school\ing\pdt\importer
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses <PackageName>_ROOT variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0074" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  CMake variable PostgreSQL_ROOT is set to:

    C:/Users/lukas/school/ing/pdt/importer/libs/pgsql

  For compatibility, CMake is ignoring the variable.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found PostgreSQL: C:/Users/lukas/school/ing/pdt/importer/libs/pgsql/lib/libpq.dll (found version "12.4") 
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/lukas/school/ing/pdt/importer/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

Therefore, you can see that the .dll is there. Also, when I compile it using WSL, it works, but not with mingw.

Comment: Most likely, libpq cannot be dynamically linked at runtime, or the version dynamically linked differs from the one against which the program was built.  Either of those could happen if you linked against a personal copy of libpq at build time, or if libpq was removed or updated after the program was built, for example.  Alternatively, your libpq may be faulty.  Or there's an outside chance that the program failure is a manifestation of the undefined behavior arising from calling a function (`PQlibVersion()`) that was not previously declared.

Comment: You could try and use an OS specific dynamic library inspector like `otool` or `ldd` to see if it reports any problems. Not sure what the DLL equivalent is for Windows.

Comment: 0xC0000135 == STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND, you are missing a DLL that is required to use the library.  So you'd google "postgresql windows dll not found", which takes you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412084/postgresql-error-the-program-cant-start-because-libpq-dll-is-missing-from-your).

Comment: I want to link postgres library from the project, how can I point compiler to it?